# Como fazer uma consulta com várias tabelas no PHP?

Tags: php, tabela-banco-de-dados

```
$sele = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE video_titulo LIKE '%$name%' OR video_chaves LIKE '%$name%'";

$query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE n_nome LIKE '%$name%' OR n_usuario LIKE '%$name%'";
```

Como fazer uma busca nas duas 2 tabelas em uma só consulta?
Assim:

```
$search="SELECT * FROM tabela1, tabela2....."
```

Comment: Tu queres fazer um `join` nas duas tabelas? Ou apenas quer trazer todos os campos de duas tabelas?

Comment: fazer uma consulta e exibir as duas tabelas em uma só busca por usuários e vídeos

Comment: Qual é o seu banco de dados?

Comment: Não deu pra entender teu comentário. `Exibir as duas tabelas`, tu quis dizer `exibir o resultado das duas tabelas`?

Comment: sim em uma só consuta

Comment: $query = $conn -> query "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE n_nome LIKE '%$name%' OR n_usuario LIKE '%$name%'";

Comment: Já tentou fazer igual no teu último exemplo? Seria algo como `SELECT t1.*, t2* FROM tabela1 t1, tabela2 t2`. Embora eu não veja um motivo claro pra você querer fazer isso, essa `query` deve funcionar.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar o comando `UNION`.

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA_1
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABELA_2
```

### ATENÇÃO

Mas para usar esse comando as tabelas devem ter o mesmo número de colunas!

### OBJEÇÃO

"Aiiiii, mas não tem. E agora ?"

### SOLUÇÃO

Coloque no `SELECT` apenas os campos que irá precisar para fazer a consulta, sendo a mesma quantidade também.

### EXEMPLO

```
SELECT ID, NOME AS RESULTADO FROM TABELA_1
UNION
SELECT ID, DESCRICAO AS RESULTADO FROM TABELA_2
```

Comment: a parte AS RESULTADO significa o que?

Comment: Significa que eu dei um **alias** para os dois campos, para você usar no seu PHP. É apenas para facilitar.

Comment: @DiegoSouza, outra "jogada" é fazer `SELECT id, nome, x FROM tabela UNION SELECT null, nome, null`. Funciona!

Comment: Sim, verdade. Anula as colunas.